# React native Clevertap push notification integration

Tags: react-native, android-push-notification, clevertap

I am trying to integrate clevertap plugin into my application. I have followed below procedure:-

1. Installed react native **clevertap plugin** using this [link](https://github.com/CleverTap/clevertap-react-native) and followed all the mention steps.
2. Also added firebase messaging package implementation in `build.gradle`
3. Added `google_service.json` file into app folder.

After doing plugin setting ***implemented Clevertap example*** and to enable push notification followed below procedure:-

- Updating user profile by setting **MSG-push** flag to **true**.
- When I am ***fetching profile information*** it's showing **push-msg** enabled as **true**

Still **I am unable to get push notification on my device**. Please let me know if I have miss anything while integration or why this problem occurs?

Also **when I check with Clevertap dashoboard**, its also showing **Push-Msg** as diabled. You can check in this image. [image: Clevertap dashboard]

Comment: have you got any solution to this.

Comment: @phpian I am not getting any solution. I have also added question on their git plugin, there also not getting solution yet.